# Resolving class from interface with Microsoft's ServiceCollection?

Tags: c#

I've been using Microsoft's ServiceCollection as a DI container recently, but I've noticed that it doesn't support resolving. I've checked all the methods and nowhere does it show it supports resolving.

I need to resolve a singleton I created with an interface, to use the instance elsewhere out of the scope it was created in. Is there a reason for this? This is for property injection I need it for.

Comment: the service collection is used to collect and register all services. from there you build a service provider out of the collection in order to resolve desired services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service collection is used to collect and register all services. From there you build a service provider out of the collection in order to resolve desired services.

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();

services.AddSingleton<IService, Service>();

//...add other services

IServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

IService service = serviceProvider.GetService<IService>();
```

If you want to be able to assign one service to another via property injection, then  take advantage of the factory delegate which has access to the provider as an argument.

For example

```
services.AddTransient<IProvider>(sp => new Provider() {
    ServiceProperty = sp.GetService<IService>()
});
```

when `IProvider` is being resolved, the deferred factory delegate will be invoked and the provider will be used to inject the dependency as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the service collection extensions below and can be found at [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1#design-services-for-dependency-injection)

```
// Services that implement IDisposable:
public class Service1 : IDisposable {}
public class Service2 : IDisposable {}
public class Service3 : IDisposable {}

public class SomeServiceImplementation : ISomeService, IDisposable {}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // The container creates the following instances and disposes them automatically:
    services.AddScoped<Service1>();
    services.AddSingleton<Service2>();
    services.AddSingleton<ISomeService>(sp => new SomeServiceImplementation());


    // The container doesn't create the following instances, so it doesn't dispose of
    // the instances automatically:
    services.AddSingleton<Service3>(new Service3());
    services.AddSingleton(new Service3());
}
```